# C#: more resilient soap parsing?

Tags: c#, .net, soap

Is there any way to make the SOAP-parsing in C# less sucky? Using service references and this drives me nuts! (because for instance it forces synchronized rollouts).

1. don't break down if new fields are added (sadly, can't influence the ordering of the fields on the other end, they are always alphabetical)
2. possibly allow case insensitivity

Any hints welcome :)

PS: and yes I know, that this is "by design", and I would gladly dump SOAP for any number of other more suitable protocols. Sadly, as much as I would like to switch away from it, this won't be happening any time soon the way I see it.

Comment: SOAP names case sensitive. So second is imposible. If Service change names in contract (wsdl), then all service consumers must adjust. It's break change. Service consumeers have no defence from service developers

Comment: New fields in service entities should not break your code. New xml (new serialized properties) just skiped when soap response is parsing to create your objects

Comment: @Ivan sadly, that is incorrect.